# Entity Framework 4 - Delete Object

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have 3 Tables in my DataBase

```
CmsMasterPages
CmsMasterPagesAdvSlots (Pure Juction Table)
CmsAdvSlots
```

Here a Picture of my EDM:

### [image]

I need find out all objects CmsAdvSlot connected with a CmsMasterPage (it is working in my code posted belove),
and **DELETE** the result (CmsAdvSlot) from the DataBase.

My Problem is **I am not able to DELETE this Objects** when I found theme.

```
Error: The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the ObjectStateManager.
```

---

```
        int findMasterPageId = Convert.ToInt32(uxMasterPagesListSelector.SelectedValue);
        CmsMasterPage myMasterPage = context.CmsMasterPages.FirstOrDefault(x => x.MasterPageId == findMasterPageId);
        var resultAdvSlots = myMasterPage.CmsAdvSlots;
        // It is working until here
        foreach (var toDeleteAdv in resultAdvSlots)
        {
            context.DeleteObject(myMasterPage.CmsAdvSlots.Any()); // ERORR HERE!!
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

---

Any idea how to solve it? Thanks for your time! :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
while (myMasterPage.CmsAdvSlots.Count > 0)
{
  var slot = myMasterPage.CmsAdvSlots.First();
  myMasterPage.CmsAdvSlots.Remove(slot); // This is required only in some scenarios - it depends on type of entities you are using.
  context.DeleteObject(slot);
}

context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Hi, i tried but i get an error: Error 1 Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection<WebProject.DataAccess.DatabaseModels.CmsAdvSlot>'

Comment: @GlbboK: Ok, I modified the example.

Comment: Another error now: Unable to update the EntitySet 'CmsMasterPagesAdvSlots' because it has a DefiningQuery and no <DeleteFunction> element exists in the <ModificationFunctionMapping> element to support the current operation......

Comment: @GlbboK: There is some problem with your mapping. It says that junction table CmsMasterPagesAdvSlots (table representing M:N relation) is defined by DefiningQuery - this usually happens if you use database view instead of table or proably if your table is read only due to missing primary keys.

Comment: My Table CmsMasterPagesAdvSlots is a Many to Many Jucntion Table with NO Primary Key. Do you have any idea how to solve it? Thanks

Comment: You must mark both FKs in your junctiona table as complex PK key and update your model. It is required in EF.

Comment: Do you mean I need to ALTER the current DataBase adding 2 PK in my Junction Table? And recreate my Model? Correct? Thanks for your time. PS no other work around exist?

Comment: @GlbboK: Yes you need to alter current database and add composite PK to junction table. The only work around can be specifying stored procedure for insert, update and delete. EF requires that you define PK for each editable table.

Comment: Thank Ladislav Mrnka, In this case I would need use a SPROC mapped in EF. Thanks once again for your help on this.

Comment: What about use ATTACHTO Method? Here a resource: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757067/how-to-delete-many-to-many-relationship-in-entity-framework-without-loading-all-o

Comment: @GlbboK: Attaching is only for adding entity to ObjectContext. It itself doesn't perform anything in DB.

Comment: Thanks once again for your answer

Answer (score 0):

[`.Any()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337697.aspx) returns a boolean. Use [`.First()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348657.aspx) instead, `.First()` will in your case return the first `CmsAdvSlot`.

If you want to remove all `CmsAdvSlot` I would follow @Ladislav Mrnka's example.

Comment: Hi Filip, now i get an error in the next line "Unable to update the EntitySet 'CmsMasterPagesAdvSlots' because it has a DefiningQuery and no <DeleteFunction> element exists in the <ModificationFunctionMapping> element to support the current operation."} any idea?

Comment: @GlbboK: So you are working with readonly entities. Are those entities mapped to DB views?

Comment: Sorry but i do not understand your question about DB View? Anyway these objects I need to remove are accessible using Navigational Property. any ideas? thanks

Comment: For Filip, I tried again your code an now I receive another error: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute

Answer (score 0):

In `context.DeleteObject(myMasterPage.CmsAdvSlots.Any());`
`myMasterPage.CmsAdvSlots.Any()` should return you a bool
You should try using `myMasterPage.CmsAdvSlots.First()` instead!

Comment: Hi, i get another error now: Unable to update the EntitySet 'CmsMasterPagesAdvSlots' because it has a DefiningQuery and no <DeleteFunction> element exists in the <ModificationFunctionMapping> element to support the current operation."} any idea?

Comment: @GIbboK:Are these entities tied to a DB View underneath?

Comment: Hi, these object are in DataBase CmsMasterPagesAdvSlots, but you can access these object using navigational property. Hope I was able to reply your question.