# EF: how to delete many-to-many relationship without loading more than is needed

Tags: c#, entity-framework, many-to-many, dbcontext

Given the entities: `Topics` and `Subscriptions` with many-to-many relationship and the corresponding tables: `Topics`, `Subscriptions`, `TopicsSubscriptions`, I want to delete only one row from `TopicsSubscriptions` using EF, but without loading any extra data (except of maybe only 1 topic and 1 subscription).

In the end I want EF to generate similar SQL to this:

```
exec sp_executesql N'delete [dbo].[TopicSubscriptions]
where (([TopicId] = @0) and ([SubscriptionId] = @1))',N'@0 int,@1 int',@0=1,@1=2
```

I have `LazyLoading` set to `false`.

I thought I could take the answer from here: [How to delete many-to-many relationship in Entity Framework without loading all of the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757067/how-to-delete-many-to-many-relationship-in-entity-framework-without-loading-all).

> ```
> var db = new TopicDBEntities(); var topic = db.Topics.FirstOrDefault(x => x.TopicId == 1);
>
> // Get the subscription you want to delete var subscription =
> db.Subscriptions.FirstOrDefault(x => x.SubscriptionId == 2);
>
> // !!! This line does not work for me (Attach to ICollection<> ?!?) !!!
> topic.Subscriptions.Attach(subscription); // Attach it (theObjectContext now 'thinks' it belongs to the topic)
>
> topic.Subscriptions.Remove(subscription); // Remove it
> db.SaveChanges(); // Flush changes
> ```

But then I realized there is no `Attach` method belonging to `ICollection<>`... unless I am missing something.

Idea of attaching only one subscription to a topic sounds good, but I cannot understand how to achieve it.

I am using `DbContext` instead of `ObjectContext` and Entity Framework 6 but I guess it should not matter.

**EDIT:** Would be good to find a solution without stored procedures, or direct sql, if possible, since I have to support many database back-ends in my app.

In case I was not clear enough, I don't need to delete the entities, I just need to remove the association between them.

Comment: if you don't want any of my solutions below then you need to add a Payload column to the table so that it gets mapped in EF and can be referenced as `dbContext.TopicSubscriptions`.  However, that means you've unnecessary data on the table using unnecessary space.  Other than that, I don't believe you have an alternative.

Comment: I should note to the above, it will affect your existing code.  TO what extent, only you will know that.

Comment: maybe my question was not clear enough, I could load only one particular topic and only one particular subscription from db, although I guess these could be attached to the DbSet<> as well.

Comment: In the question you have linked dannie.f's answer is a working solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15294368/270591

Comment: Exactly what I just tried now as well and worked like a charm... Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Slauma was also saying in his comments, the solution was to *attach* entities as "dannie.f" did in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15294368/270591) :

> ```
> var db = new TopicDBEntities();
>
> var topic = new Topic { TopicId = 1 };
> var subscription = new Subscription { SubscriptionId = 2};
> topic.Subscriptions.Add(subscription);
>
> // Attach the topic and subscription as unchanged 
> // so that they will not be added to the db   
> // but start tracking changes to the entities
> db.Topics.Attach(topic);
>
> // Remove the subscription
> // EF will know that the subscription should be removed from the topic
> topic.subscriptions.Remove(subscription);
>
> // commit the changes
> db.SaveChanges();
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've mapped it so that you can't directly reference TopicSubscriptions, and only Topics and Subscriptions, the following applies.

```
// Add a subscription to a topic
var subscription = dbContect.Subscriptions.Find(2);
var topic = dbContext.Topics.Find(1);

// Recommend checking here, but omitted for example

// Make the association
topic.Subscriptions.Add(subscription);

// Update
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

To remove a subscription from a Topic

```
// Remove
topic.Subscriptions.Remove(subscription);

// Update
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

If you know the Ids however and want to remove it directly, I recommend a simple StoredProcedure on the database accepting @topicId and @subscriptionId and removing the entry in TSQL.

```
@topicId INT,
@subscriptionId INT

DELETE FROM [dbo].[TopicSubscriptions] WHERE TopicId = @topicId AND SubscriptionId = @subscriptionId;
```

You can then map the StoredProcedure to EF6 and call it from your context.

```
using (DbContext dbContext = new DbContext())
{
dbContext.DeleteTopicSubscriptionStoredProcedure(topicId, subscriptionId);
}
```

EDIT
Given only the SP option works (apologies for missing Lazy-Loading false), you can alternatively execute SQL directly from dbContext.

```
using (var dbContext = new DbContext())
{
string sql = @"DELETE FROM [dbo].[TopicSubscriptions] WHERE TopicId = @p0 AND SubscriptionId = @p1";
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql, topicId, subscriptionId);
}
```

Comment: Well, your code to delete relationship will not work, since inner collections are not loaded (LazyLoading set to false). Stored procedure would work indeed, but there must be a way with EF as well.

Comment: @Cristi - OK. I missed that part (yes, despite it being highlighted)!  Edited (in two mins time) to add a third option, but I still feel the Stored Procedure is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest letting entity framework handle the deletion by declaring `cascade on delete` in the fluent api like this;

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
            .HasOptional(p => p.Category)
            .WithMany()
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

the full solution is outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5471661/3002953).

Comment: I don't need to delete the entities, I just need to remove the association between them

Comment: Well that wouldn't work then haha Surely you would end up with a lot of redundant data?!